# Overloading inherited constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, inherited-constructors

Given the following base class:

```
class Base {
    int a, b;
public:
    Base(int a, int b=42): a(a), b(b) { }
};
```

And a class that is derived from base:

```
class Derived: public Base {
    using Base::Base; // inherit Base constructors
    bool c;
public:
    Derived(int a): Base(a), c(true) { }
    Derived(int a, int b): Base(a, b), c(true) { }
};
```

---

Is there a way to avoid having to create two separate constructors for `Derived` and instead overload the inherited `Base` constructors to initialize the extra member of `Derived`?

I was thinking to use something like this:

```
template <typename... Args, 
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<Base, Args&&...>, int> = 0>
explicit Derived(Args&&... args):
    Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...), c(true) {}
```

This is close, but is too verbose and does not work if the the base class's constructors are inherited. i.e. if `using Base::Base` is present in the class (then it defaults to those constructors and does not initialize the field `b`).

It works if the base class inherited constructors are not present i.e. removing `using Base::Base`.

---

Is this the only way to have this work? i.e. by removing `using Base::Base` and using a variadic template constructor in each derived class? Is there a less verbose way to overload the inherited constructors?

I am using C++17.

Comment: Do you really mean private derivation? Also, I don't think your base class can compile `error: 'Base::Base(int, int)' cannot be overloaded with 'Base::Base(int, int)'`

Comment: `Base(int, int) {...} Base(int, int=42) {...}` isn't legal.  Can you show a more accurate representation?

Comment: Is the question just, how do you initialize `b` to `true`?

Comment: @Barry pretty much yes

Comment: @NeilButterworth, that should work now. I didn't test this and meant it more as pseudocode, but I will run it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case all you need to do is provide `c` with an in class initializer

```
class Derived : public Base {
    using Base::Base;
    bool c = true;
};
```

allows you to use `Base`'s constructors and will initialize `c` to `true` in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware that the default initialization would occur after the base class members are initialized which is why I went this longer route of using variadic template constructors

Comment: @smac89 All base classes are initialized before the derived object so you just get the right behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you're looking for is a way to inherit `Base`'s constructors while just initializing members of `Derived` to something specific. For that, we can use a default member initializer:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    using Base::Base;
private:
    bool c = true;
};
```

Constructing a `Derived(42)` will invoke the `Base(int)` constructor, but also initialize `c` to `true`.

Comment: What if the value of `c` depends on one of the other fields in `Base`. Are those fields guaranteed to be initialized before this default initialization occurs?

Comment: @smac89 Yes, initialization order of subobjects in C++ is _always_ declaration order.

Comment: Perfect. That was what I was really after.